# How to update key values behalf of Id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have these JavaScript objects

```
var oldObject=[{ 
            id:1,
            key:'name', 
            fiendSize:'6', 
            fromPlaceHolder:'', 
            fieldInstruction:'',
            filedType:'input', 
            lable:"Single Line ", 
            type:'text', 
            formValidation: {
                required:false
            }
        }];


var newObject=  { 
            id:1,
            key:'name', 
            fiendSize:'12', 
            fromPlaceHolder:'Enter Your Name', 
            fieldInstruction:'please Enter string only',
            filedType:'input', 
            lable:"Single Line ", 
            type:'text', 
            formValidation: {
                required:true
            }
        };
```

I need to replace/update the oldObject value with newObject value from with the same id.

So here is the result I want to get:

```
var oldObject = [{ 
            id:1,
            key:'name', 
            fiendSize:'12', 
            fromPlaceHolder:'Enter Your Name', 
            fieldInstruction:'please Enter string only',
            filedType:'input', 
            lable:"Single Line ", 
            type:'text', 
            formValidation: {
                required:true
            }]
```

How can I implement it using JavaScript in react js ?

Comment: Note that `oldObject` is an array of objects and `newObject` is a single object.

Comment: Also no react specific code needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` like:

```js
var oldObject = [{
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '6',
  fromPlaceHolder: '',
  fieldInstruction: '',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: false
  }
}];


var newObject = {
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '12',
  fromPlaceHolder: 'Enter Your Name',
  fieldInstruction: 'please Enter string only',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: true
  }
};

let result = [{}];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(oldObject[0])) {
  result[0][key] = newObject[key];
}
console.log(result);
```

Reference:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

P.S. i used new object but you can update the old object and i hardcoded the array number so if you have more then 1 you need to use `for-loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is React you should be looking towards [immutable data structures](https://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/pros-and-cons-of-using-immutability-with-react-js/).

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects that don't match the id, and then add in the updated object.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 3 }
];

const newArr = [
  ...arr.filter(obj => obj.id !== 2),
  { id: 2, name: 'Billy Joel' }
];

console.log(newArr);
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.map` and merge 2 object by `{...existItem, ...newObject}`.

```js
var oldObject = [{
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '6',
  fromPlaceHolder: '',
  fieldInstruction: '',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: false
  }
}];

var newObject = {
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '12',
  fromPlaceHolder: 'Enter Your Name',
  fieldInstruction: 'please Enter string only',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: true
  }
};

var result = oldObject.map(item => {
   var existItem = oldObject.find(e => e.id == newObject.id);
   if (existItem) {
      return {...existItem, ...newObject};
   }
   return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oldObject = [{
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '6',
  fromPlaceHolder: '',
  fieldInstruction: '',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: false
  }
}];


var newObject = {
  id: 1,
  key: 'name',
  fiendSize: '12',
  fromPlaceHolder: 'Enter Your Name',
  fieldInstruction: 'please Enter string only',
  filedType: 'input',
  lable: "Single Line ",
  type: 'text',
  formValidation: {
    required: true
  }
};


const findByIdWithIndex = oldObject.findIndex(d => d.id === newObject.id)

if (findByIdWithIndex !== -1) {
  // Found the Old object id Matching with new object id
  oldObject[findByIdWithIndex] = { ...newObject
  }
}

console.log("Updated oldObject :", oldObject)
```

Update the Index found with new object Id to old Object Id's index and replace it.